# Java Robot class not working the same way in Ubuntu than in Windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, awtrobot

I have this code workin perfectly in windows 10, but in Ubuntu 16 it moves to the coordinates but not clicking. Is this a know-issue? What alternatives can I use in ubuntu?

```
        robot.mouseMove(x,y);
        robot.delay(1000);
        try {

            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException a){
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Try to put a delay between mousePress and mouseRelease. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: What happens when you use a delay?

Comment: I haven't solve it yet but it has to do with the delays and not with the robot class. Thanks!